# How to convert map with List as key to collection of merged list values?

Tags: java, algorithm, java-8

I have a structure that looks like this:

```
Map<Long, List<Double>
```

I want to convert it to

```
List<Double>
```

where each item in this resulting list represents sum of the values for one key. With example Map:

```
{1: [2.0, 3.0, 4.0],
 2: [1.5, 10.0]}
```

I want to achieve as a result:

```
[9.0, 11.5]
```

or

```
[11.5, 9.0]
```

(order doesn't matter).
Is it possible with Java 8 merge() method?
Actually the case above is a little bit simplified, because in fact my List is parametrized with some complex class and I want to create merged object of this class but I just want to grasp the general idea here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
Map<Long, List<Double>> map = // ...
List<Double> sums = map.values()
                       .stream()
                       .map(l -> l.stream().mapToDouble(d -> d).sum())
                       .collect(Collectors.toList())
```